# Prevent user account lockout for hacks/failed-logins to RDWeb (Remote Desktop Web Access)

Tags: rdp, remote, remote-desktop-services, remote-desktop-gateway, rdweb

How can I prevent RDWeb (Remote Desktop Web Access) attempting to authenticate/login ANY user on the domain!? I was under the impression only users configured in our CAP (Connection Access Policy) & RAP (Resource Access Policy) were allowed to login. However a user not in those policies was able to login successfully. Intentional wrong passwords were tried for that user confirming it could be locked out on the domain, which is the exact issue we're facing occasionally. I'm guessing someone on the internet is trying to hack in using that username.

**Things I've tried:**

- I've setup '[Remote Access Account Lockout](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff687746(v=ws.10).aspx)' on the sole RDS server, but it doesn't appear to be working. The account is still being locked out & the registry subkey `domain name:user name` isn't being created. Can this even work with RDWeb?
- [Denying certain users the read rights to `%WinDir%\Web\RDWeb`](http://www.vkernel.ro/blog/restrict-users-from-login-to-remote-desktop-web-access) blocked certain users successfully logging in, but those same user accounts could still be locked-out after bad password attempts.

We're going to be using DirectAccess in the near future & remote access configuration might even be handled by someone else so we're looking for easy/free solutions!

Comment: `I was under the impression only users configured in our CAP (Connection Access Policy) & RAP (Resource Access Policy) were allowed to login.` - Yes, but that doesn't prevent "hackers" from attempting to log in. If a "hacker" attempts to log in using a valid user account and exceeds the account lockout threshold then the account is going to be locked out. That's the entire point of having an account lockout policy.

Comment: Then why does that 'Remote Access Account Lockout' allow you to set a different threshold (AD lockout could be set to 5, whilst the remote lockout could be set to 3)? It's two different concepts we're trying handle: local AD authentication, remote access utilizing AD authentication. I'm trying to limit the users for remote AD authentication

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question then. I read your question as "Why is the account lockout setting locking out accounts on failed login attempts?" and my response is "That's what it's supposed to do."

Comment: I don't want RDWeb to allow every domain user to login as I have one user (with a simple username) who consistently gets locked out because of random people on internet trying to login. Does that make sense? How can I re-word the question to get a better response? I apologize if I came off testy before, I did spent awhile trying to word it the best & it still was misunderstood :( Thanks for your responses & trying to understand :)